# VisualSVN 2.59 email notification detailed-subject option failing

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have a post-commit hook setup for email notification.  Emails are coming in ok, but if I add in the option for detailed-subject, it complains about an invalid option.  Does Version 2.59 support that option?

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
    commit-notification  "%1"  -r %2 ^
    --from "noreply@nowhere.com" --to "somebody@somewhere.com" ^
    --smtp-server mail.somecompany.com ^
    --detailed-subject
```

The error message is something like:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
VisualSVNServerHooks.exe: invalid option: --detailed-subject
Type 'VisualSVNServerHooks help' for usage.
```

**[update]**
Yep, I found it listed here as available in 2.6 onward
https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/2.6/
*New options for commit notification hook handler: '--no-html', '--detailed-subject', '--filter'.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `--detailed-subject` option was added in VisualSVN Server 2.6.0. Read the article [KB18: Configuring Email Notifications in VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/) to learn more about command line options available in current email commit notifier versions.

Upgrade to VisualSVN Server 4.2 is recommended for all users. Upgrade is easy and straightforward, but we strongly advise reading the [KB161: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 4.2](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00161/) article beforehand (especially if you are upgrading from VisualSVN Server 3.9 or older versions).

You can always download the latest VisualSVN Server version from the [main download page](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00161/).